# Add share link to comment menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app

It'd be nice if the iOS app gave you a share link for comments like it does questions and answers. Currently that option isn't available:

[image: comment menu]

My [Twitter ramblings](https://twitter.com/tmslft/status/483821340965998592) will thank you.

Comment: Amazing how nobody didn't come with this idea before! :)

Comment: Didn't they not, @Shadow?

Comment: I would add, this would be equally nice in a regular browser too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice little feature suggestion.

It is currently available in the latest Beta release, version 1.0.1.89.

[image: Screenshot of comment sharing feature]